# Why Storm supervisors shutting down automatically

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I have configured Storm cluster of 1 nimbus, 1 zookeeper, 1 supervisor on single node cluster.  My Nimbus and UI are working fine but supervisor is not working as expected and it is showing in UI for only few minutes.

Following are my supervisor logs

```
[31/10/14 05:46:00:000 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: 11f31d37-a7a1-4b91-b014-a49d7a65c9e0 still hasn't started
[31/10/14 05:46:01:001 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: 11f31d37-a7a1-4b91-b014-a49d7a65c9e0 still hasn't started
[31/10/14 05:46:01:001 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: 11f31d37-a7a1-4b91-b014-a49d7a65c9e0 still hasn't started
[31/10/14 05:46:02:002 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Worker 11f31d37-a7a1-4b91-b014-a49d7a65c9e0 failed to start
[31/10/14 05:46:02:002 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Worker 23cb938b-9295-4aea-b0dc-030afaef737c failed to start
[31/10/14 05:46:02:002 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Worker cd25c3c8-6e0f-4bc5-88d4-687c17de582c failed to start
[31/10/14 05:46:02:002 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Worker e71816a2-0231-4dee-9423-ff02231e6b6f failed to start
[31/10/14 05:46:02:002 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Shutting down and clearing state for id 11f31d37-a7a1-4b91-b014-a49d7a65c9e0. Current supervisor time: 1414757762. State: :not-started, Heartbeat: nil
[31/10/14 05:46:02:002 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Shutting down 4783ca79-02d2-4df5-b196-d83670af60a4:11f31d37-a7a1-4b91-b014-a49d7a65c9e0
ERROR: The process "9000" not found.
[31/10/14 05:46:04:004 IST]  INFO storm.util: Error when trying to kill 9000. Process is probably already dead.
[31/10/14 05:46:04:004 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Shut down 4783ca79-02d2-4df5-b196-d83670af60a4:11f31d37-a7a1-4b91-b014-a49d7a65c9e0
[31/10/14 05:46:04:004 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Shutting down and clearing state for id 23cb938b-9295-4aea-b0dc-030afaef737c. Current supervisor time: 1414757762. State: :not-started, Heartbeat: nil
[31/10/14 05:46:04:004 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Shutting down 4783ca79-02d2-4df5-b196-d83670af60a4:23cb938b-9295-4aea-b0dc-030afaef737c
ERROR: The process "9060" not found.
[31/10/14 05:46:04:004 IST]  INFO storm.util: Error when trying to kill 9060. Process is probably already dead.
[31/10/14 05:46:04:004 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Shut down 4783ca79-02d2-4df5-b196-d83670af60a4:23cb938b-9295-4aea-b0dc-030afaef737c
[31/10/14 05:46:04:004 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Shutting down and clearing state for id cd25c3c8-6e0f-4bc5-88d4-687c17de582c. Current supervisor time: 1414757762. State: :not-started, Heartbeat: nil
[31/10/14 05:46:04:004 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Shutting down 4783ca79-02d2-4df5-b196-d83670af60a4:cd25c3c8-6e0f-4bc5-88d4-687c17de582c
ERROR: The process "9172" not found.
[31/10/14 05:46:05:005 IST]  INFO storm.util: Error when trying to kill 9172. Process is probably already dead.
[31/10/14 05:46:05:005 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Shut down 4783ca79-02d2-4df5-b196-d83670af60a4:cd25c3c8-6e0f-4bc5-88d4-687c17de582c
[31/10/14 05:46:05:005 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Shutting down and clearing state for id e71816a2-0231-4dee-9423-ff02231e6b6f. Current supervisor time: 1414757762. State: :not-started, Heartbeat: nil
[31/10/14 05:46:05:005 IST]  INFO daemon.supervisor: Shutting down 4783ca79-02d2-4df5-b196-d83670af60a4:e71816a2-0231-4dee-9423-ff02231e6b6f
ERROR: The process "7604" not found.
```

Comment: Are your bolts throwing errors? Exceptions thrown from a bolt will kill the entire worker...

Comment: Sorry, I forget to update this question. Yes there was some exceptions, so it killed the workers. any way thank you brother